# Suspend Modern UI app to taskbar

Tags: windows-8

Is there a way to "minimize" a Modern UI app to the traditional taskbar? I feel that having to manage **two** kind of taskbar, one horizontal and one vertical is too cumbersome. Is there a way to merge them into one so that I can better track the apps (both desktop and modern UI) that I have opened?

Comment: No, because the Taskbar is from a different paradigm and is eventually going away.

Comment: why is this get downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in Windows 8.1.

In the Modern UI `PC settings` page, go to `PC and devices` > `Corners and edges` > `Show Windows Store apps on the taskbar`.

This will show all Modern UI apps--now referred to as Windows Store apps--in the taskbar.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to merge them into one so that I can better track the apps (both desktop and modern UI) that I have opened?

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> will show a list of all of your currently running apps, regardless of whether they are Desktop apps or Modern UI apps.

As far as I know, there is not a way to pin a Metro App to the taskbar. You can pin a Desktop app to the Start Screen, but this will not show whether it is running.

If you swipe-in from the left, you will see a list of all your running apps, but "Desktop" will count as a single app, regardless of how many Desktop apps you are running. So I think <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> is the closest to what you want.

Answer (score 1):

[KB2919355](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2919355) (aka Update 1) adds the option to show immersive applications on taskbar, which is enabled by default.