# Force a non-metro app to run fullscreen outside the desktop?

Tags: windows-8, fullscreen, modern-ui

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Suspend Modern UI app to taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/491846/suspend-modern-ui-app-to-taskbar)

In Windows 8, is there a way to make a normally desktop-only app run outside of the desktop? For normal apps that can be fullscreen, I'd rather switch through them using the metro switcher rather than switching to the desktop and then alt+tabbing.

Comment: Question possibly covers similar ground to [Suspend Modern UI app to taskbar](http://superuser.com/questions/491846/suspend-modern-ui-app-to-taskbar)? Accepted answer certainly does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

Using <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (what you call the metro task switcher) all desktop applications appear as a single item. 10 desktop apps running? Still, just a single item in the list - "desktop".

Using <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> (what we use in Windows 7) all desktop apps appear individually - including Store apps (what I am sure you would call metro apps). This is the way it works (even if it seems a hair inconsistent). <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> is certainly the superset of the two commands.

If you want to task switch between all your desktop apps, <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> is the only way to do it. Otherwise, your desktop apps appear as one item. That's just the way it is.

I hope this helps.

Comment: That's a shame. Ah well- thanks for the clarification!