# Promote a Windows 8.1 desktop app to be a Modern app?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, modern-ui

Trying to get used to the whole windows 8 thing and don't appreciate the bipolarness, like a lot of people do.  I've seen a lot of people try to fix this by making Modern apps windowed (using ModernMix or something), but how about doing the opposite -- making desktop apps modern apps?  Being able to close them and switch them with the same touch gestures.  That's the main thing.

So someone asked this for Windows 8 [Force a non-metro app to run fullscreen outside the desktop?](https://superuser.com/questions/492305/force-a-non-metro-app-to-run-fullscreen-outside-the-desktop)

It's been asked several times actually

Not sure if it's yet possible for Windows 8.1

Comment: possible duplicate of [Force a non-metro app to run fullscreen outside the desktop?](http://superuser.com/questions/492305/force-a-non-metro-app-to-run-fullscreen-outside-the-desktop), [Can I wrap Windows 8 desktop apps in Modern UI?](http://superuser.com/questions/497945/can-i-wrap-windows-8-desktop-apps-in-modern-ui?rq=1)

Comment: "It's been asked several times actually" - Please don't re-ask the same question.  Instead, to garner newer/better answers, [place a bounty](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) and some comments on the existing one.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible. Windows 8.1 still does not allow running desktop apps in the way you suggest.